# JPanel ontop of other JPanels

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, overlap

I would like to make a JPanel pop up over an other JPanel in java. However I can not find anything useful on the internet. I tried playing around with absolute positioning but things like buttons from the bottom layer are showing through the top layer.
I uploaded a really ugly drawing of what I want to do.
Is there an easy way of doing this?

[image]

Edit:
I tried to make what "Ulkra" suggested. Here is the code and a screenshot:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JPanel foregroundPanel = new JPanel();      
    foregroundPanel.setVisible(false);
    foregroundPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    foregroundPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(foregroundPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel backgroungPanel = new JPanel();      
    backgroungPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    backgroungPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(backgroungPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        backgroungPanel.add(new JButton("BackgroundBtn " + i));
    }       
    foregroundPanel.add(new JButton("ForegroundBtn 1"));

    JButton makeVisibleBtn = new JButton("+");
    makeVisibleBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            foregroundPanel.setVisible(true);
        }
    });     
    backgroungPanel.add(makeVisibleBtn);        

    JButton makeInvisibleBtn = new JButton("-");
    makeInvisibleBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            foregroundPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
    });     
    foregroundPanel.add(makeInvisibleBtn);      

    panel.add(backgroungPanel);
    panel.add(foregroundPanel);

    frame.add(panel);
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: where's the code with what you have tried?

Comment: Please show your code and give us a exact problem to help you with.

Comment: Use an undecorated JDialog as the popup window.

Comment: undecorated JDialog is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: I found a problem with that solution. The JDialog does not move with the main JFrame. Can it somehow be fixed to the position of a JFrame?

Answer (score -3):

For this, you have to use a Panel (if you are using NetBeans, you can find it in Swing Containers) and in the constuctor of the Frame, you have to SET IT AS UNVISIBLE, so you need the buttom to see it: (In this example, i call my Panel as "jPanel1" and i put a buttom in it)

```
public Main() {
    initComponents();
    jPanel1.setVisible(false);//<-- This!
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Then, you create the buttom to "activate it" and but this code in:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jPanel1.setVisible(true);
}
```

(And of course, if you wanna set it as unvisible you just have to do the same as in the constructor).

I test it and it works:(Imgur is not working so excuse i have to use postimg.org)
https://postimg.org/gallery/1z6fpajva/

Now you could put a border so you can differentiate your new Panel from your other Frame:
https://postimg.org/image/mdpf7hvxx/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The problem with that solution is that the invisible panel has to be there all the time, blocking the space. I want it to be on top of everything else. Like in Gmail, when you write a new mail. There is a popup over the rest of the layout, without interfering with it.